# How to put the a Dependency Property in Resource Dictionary for the purpose of reuse?

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I have the following class

```
public class ChartBase:FrameworkElement, INotifyPropertyChanged
{ 
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Header), typeof(object),typeof(ChartBase));

   public object Header
   {
    get { return (bool)GetValue(IsSpinningProperty); }
    set { SetValue(IsSpinningProperty, value); }
  }

}
```

And usually this is how I consume it in XAML:

```
    <ChartBase.Header>
        <TextBlock Foreground="Black" 
                   FontFamily="Segoe UI" 
                   Margin="0,0,0,20" 
                   Text="{Binding Header}"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </ChartBase.Header>
```

I want to put the above `ChartBase.Header` in Resource Dictionary, because my chart header needs to have consistent format across the application. Something like

```
<Style TargetType="GroupBox" x:Key="SecondGB" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type FrameworkElement}}">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />

</Style>
```

How can this be done ( and at the same time the `DataContext.Header`) is still binded correctly? If this is not possible, what is the next best way to write the code so that these Header information can be easily reused?

Comment: I guess you mean a style for ChartBase where the Header is the TextBlock ? You cannot put the property itself in resource dictionary.

Comment: @NawedNabiZada, Yes, I want a style for ChartBase

Comment: How does the `GroupBox` relate to the `TextBlock` that you set the `Header` property to...?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, FrameworkElement cannot be templated, so I would say go one level lower (higher ?!?) and use Control instead: 
[Control class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.control?view=netframework-4.8)

Then in your ChartBase HeaderProperty you get and set something else?!?

I have allowed myself to modify it like this:

```
public class ChartBase : Control, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Header), typeof(object), typeof(ChartBase));

    public object Header
    {
        get => (bool)GetValue(HeaderProperty);
        set => SetValue(HeaderProperty, value);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

And then you can style it like this:

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type myProject:ChartBase}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type myProject:ChartBase}">
                    <TextBlock Foreground="Red" 
                           FontFamily="Segoe UI" 
                           Margin="0,0,0,20" 
                           Text="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                           VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </ControlTemplate>

            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

And finally usage will be like:

```
<myProject:ChartBase Header="My Header" /> 
<!--Header can be bound to any property you want-->
```

Comment: It seems that the `Setter Property="Template"` replaces the content inside `myProject:ChartBase` and not the content inside `myProject:ChartBase.Header` ?

Comment: That is correct. You cannot template a property. In case you really want to style/template the header only, then change it from type object to something else (e.g. Control), and base your Style/Template on that type.

Comment: What if the Header is of the type `object` and I can't change it ( because the control is from third party in which I have no access to)?

Comment: How do you want to bind object to a Text property of a TextBlock ?

Comment: I guess I do not really understand your usage of this ChartBase. Dependency Property is meant to be bound. In case you already have a Header property and you want that to be bind to a TextBlock then go with the answer ASh provided. But in case there is no Header property in your control and you want to add one, then you have to create the dependency property you have created.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to declare setter for Header property in a style:

```
<TextBlock x:Key="hdr" x:Shared="False"
           Foreground="Black" 
           FontFamily="Segoe UI" 
           Margin="0,0,0,20" 
           Text="{Binding Header}"
           HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
           VerticalAlignment="Center" />

<Style TargetType="ChartBase" x:Key="SecondGB">
    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{StaticResource hdr}"/>
</Style>
```

`{Binding Header}` will be resolved in runtime, as long as DataContext has Header property.

Please note, how I declare TextBlock as a *non-shared resource*. It ensured that each ChartBase get its own TextBlock. Setter can be written as follows:

```
<Setter Property="Header">
    <Setter.Value>
        <TextBlock Foreground="Black" 
                   FontFamily="Segoe UI" 
                   Margin="0,0,0,20" 
                   Text="{Binding Header}"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

but it creates only one instance of TextBlock, which can be displayed inh only one place

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? it seems that the `Header` is set to `System.Windows.Style` type and not `TextBlock`.

Comment: @Graviton, I don't have ChartBase, but it worked for Button.Content